# Negative X-Axis Reversed in Pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm plotting from a 2 column text file where column 1 is x values and column 2 is y values. My problem is then when plotted `-3.0` is shown as larger than `-1.5`. How do I get the x-axis to display properly?

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#open and read file
with open('01_points.txt','r') as file:
    content = [i.strip().split("\t") for i in file.read().splitlines()]

#set x and y values, ignore blank lines
x = [i[0] for i in content if len(i)>=2]
y = [i[1] for i in content if len(i)>=2]

#format and show the plot
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

I'm not sure if this the source of the problem, but the first few lines of the file are:

```
0.0 0.0  
-1.5    1.5  
-3.0    3.0  
-1.5    4.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the strings your read from the file into floats:

```
x = [float(i[0]) for i in content if len(i)>=2]
y = [float(i[1]) for i in content if len(i)>=2]
```

Otherwise matplotlib sorts the strings lexicographically and `'-1.5'` is less than `-3.0'`.